# VBA code to change a link to a path set in a specific worksheet cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and running into a roadblock. In my excel file I have an existing link to a different excel file. I am looking for VBA code that would let me change that link to point to a different excel file. I also want to set a specific cell in a worksheet to the name of the new file path and reference that in the VBA code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Existing Link - "H:\Links\file1.xlsx"
New Link - "H:\Links\file2.xlsx"
Worksheet - "Sheet1"
Cell - "A1" *note that this cell will have its value set to the New Link path

Comment: Isn't this something that can be accomplished simply by Find&Replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the VBA, change the existing link to:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

Put the new path in Sheet1, A1, and you will be all set :)

Comment: Question is unclear. What does link mean here? Maybe OP has them in the formulas as references. Please avoid from posting answers when the question is not clear or has other problems.

Comment: James, thanks for the response. I was able to use your code to create my macro.